# Any workaround to use Flows in SF tabs + visualforce template

Tags: community, visual-workflow

As documented in [Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_sites_which.htm&type=5), Flows cannot be used in Salesforce Communities based on tabs + visualforce template.

We have one functionality already developed using flows, we wanted to open same for community with template - SF tabs + visualforce, but since flows are not supported wanted to know if any workaround can be done to reuse the flow instead of new development.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement your flow within a lightning component that is loaded via lightning:out into the VF Page.

I cannot attest to performance or permission challenges, though, since I haven't tested this approach. In any case the flow would run in [Classic Styles, not Lightning Styles.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208894/unstyled-flows-in-lightning-out)